# Change the class of paragraph when radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button, dom-events

I have been using the following code to change the color of `<p>` depending upon the radio button checked.
I have been using two classes red and blue,
but its not working.

So kindly help me out.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var ele = document.getElementsByName('color');


    if (ele[0].checked) { //index has to be j.
          $("p").toggleClass("blue");
    }
    else {
            $("p").toggleClass("red");
    }


</script>

<style type="text/css">

.blue
{
color:blue;
}
.red
{
color:red;  
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<input type="radio" name="color" value="blue">blue<br>

<input type="radio" name="color" value="red">red


<p>When a user clicks on a radio-button, it becomes checked, and all other radio-buttons         with equal name become unchecked.</p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As such, your javascript will be executed before your elements even exist in the DOM. You should put your javascript code at the very end of the body, or include it in an event handler triggered when your document is loaded.

The HTML :

```
<input type="radio" name="color" value="blue">blue<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red">red
<p id="myParagraph">When a user clicks on a radio-button, it becomes checked, and all other radio-buttons with equal name become unchecked.</p>
```

In Vanilla JS :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

   var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName('color');
   var paragraph = document.getElementById('myParagraph');

    for(var i=0;i< radioButtons.length;i++)
    {
        var elem = radioButtons[i];
        elem.addEventListener('change',function(e){     
            console.log(paragraph);
            if(paragraph.className)
                paragraph.className = this.value;
            else
                paragraph.classList.add(this.value);
        }
        ,false);

    }
});
```

[Fiddle of this](http://jsfiddle.net/9GT2m/)

Or, if you use jQuery and correctly include it in your page (which is not the case in your example) :

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('input:radio').on('change',function(){
        $('#myParagraph').addClass(this.value);
    });

});
```

[Fiddle of this](http://jsfiddle.net/LTUNL/)